# Почему этот код не работает?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('choise_area').innerHTML = '<input id="new"  value="Нажми Меня" onclick="alert('Спасибо!');" type="button"/>
    return false;
}
```

Comment: проверьте ковычки, что-то некоторые из них потерялись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('choise_area').innerHTML = '' +
   '<input id="new" value="Нажми Меня" type="button" onclick="alert(\'Спасибо!\');">';

  return false;
}
```

1. Экранируйте (те же) кавычки
2. Закрывайте кавычки

Answer (score 0):

Потому что нарушены правила синтаксиса

```
document.getElementById('choise_area').innerHTML = '<input id="new"  value="Нажми Меня" onclick="alert('Спасибо!');" type="button"/>';
```

в строковой константе отсутствует закрывающая кавычка.

Comment: Ваш код тем более не работает)